# How can I implement a custom C++ iterator that efficiently iterates over key-value pairs that are backed by two distinct arrays

Tags: c++, c++11, libstdc++

I want to make use of libstdc++'s [__gnu_parallel::multiway_merge](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a01112.html#a82b81744e4f5f55c8e8425c35a61fadb) to merge four **large** sequences of sorted key-value pairs at once (to save memory bandwidth). 
Each sequence of key-value pairs is represented by two distinct arrays, such that 
`values[i]` is the value associated with `keys[i]`.

The implementation for multiway-merging a single array of keys (keys-only) or an array of std::pairs would be straightforward. However, I need to implement a custom iterator that I can pass to the multiway_merge, which holds one reference to my keys array and one to the corresponding values array.

So my approach looks something like the following:

```
    template<
        typename KeyT,
        typename ValueT
    >
    class ForwardIterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, KeyT>
    {
        KeyT* k_itr;
        ValueT* v_itr;
        size_t offset;

        explicit ForwardIterator(KeyT* k_start, ValueT *v_start) : k_itr(k_start), v_itr(v_start), offset(0)
        {
        }
        ForwardIterator& operator++ () // Pre-increment
        {
            offset++;
            return *this;
        }
    }
```

However, the problems start as soon as I'm getting to the overloading of the dereferencing operator.

Help is really appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking what you should return when you dereference the iterator?

Comment: Have you looked at boost zip iterator?  Second, there is a problem whereby forward and stronger iterators must return under the standard a *reference* to the underlying data, which implies it must actually exist.  The exact requirments of `multiway_merge` may have to be examined; does it need random access iterators or forward iterators, or just input iterators?

Comment: NathanOliver: At least, that's where I'm getting stuck.
@Yakk: I'm afraid I won't get around a random access iterator. Still hoping, there's a reasonable solution to this...

Comment: @elste does the library need a full random access iterator?  Or just mostly?  Chrck the docs and source code.